# Angular 2 Image folder not watch

Tags: image, angular, compilation

Image folder changes are not reflecting in the angular2 application, Unless i start server again by doing ng serve. How can i keep watch on particular image folder, if images are getting updated,deleted

**structure:** src/images

Would be great help !

Comment: How you are deleting the images? `shift + Del`? Are you reading the number of images in the folder? Where is your code? Which programming you used?

Comment: I am creating a image and copying to image folder. but was unable to load image in angular 2 application in the view. But it is detecting when i start the server again by doing ng serve.

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: Its just my assets are not compiling when some changes occur to image folder or css. Code is proper but image and css folder are not having watch

Comment: I think they should be defined in the `gulp` file to watch changes. But your problem is displaying the images in the view right. Not watching whether they are created or deleted

Comment: I am using npm, i have angular-cli.json

Comment: Yes Mr perfect,It can be seen when i start server again, but not before that

Comment: I don't know about angular-cli detection but https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer see this

Comment: This is expected functionality of the angular cli. ng serve starts up a webpack dev server and loads your assets into virtual memory. You are required to restart your webpack dev server (ng serve) whenever your assets folder changes.

Comment: @LLai I'm facing the exact same issue,, there must be a way to recompile assets without running ng serve

Comment: @AzoulayJason you would need a way to push the file to the webpack dev server. Why do you need the assets folder to update?

Comment: @LLai Because this is where I store every picture the client send. Maybe you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006908/image-folder-is-not-being-watched-when-i-upload-a-file-in-angular2?noredirect=1#comment78974830_46006908

Comment: @AzoulayJason I get Page not found for that question.

Comment: @AffanShaikh I am facing the same issue, Please let me know how do you resolved this. thank you.

Comment: @Rush1312 the current version keeps all those files under watch, well I was pretty new to angular 4, so couldn't understand the workflow

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, this is expected functionality when using ng serve. The cli does have some documentation on how to mimic ng serve with the ng build command. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-disk-serve

This way ng build will actually write to the disk and the watch flag will allow your app to rebuild. Now the updated assets will be available.

Original Comment

> This is expected functionality of the angular cli. ng serve starts up a webpack dev server and loads your assets into virtual memory. You are required to restart your webpack dev server (ng serve) whenever your assets folder changes

Comment: Hey That will be available after the build ?, what if am working on localhost ?

Comment: yep they will be available. Everytime you add a file to the assets the first process (ng build --watch) will detect the change and rebuild. This would likely only be for localhost